# Doing columns with a for loop on a nested list

Tags: python

I'm trying to get:

```
 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30
31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40
41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49   50
51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59   60
61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70
71   72   73   74   75   76   77   78   79   80
81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89   90
91   92   93   94   95   96   97   98   99  100
```

from this:

```
# nums is a range object
nums = list(range(1, 101))
chunks = []
print(nums)
print()

for i in range(0, len(nums), 10):
    chunks.append(nums[i:i+10])
```

in Python.... I can't for the life of me solve it.

Comment: You want to print the numbers that way or have a list of lists containing 10 numbers each?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use nested loops to print chunks out like that. Here's an example:

```
for i in chunks:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should produce exactly the same output as in the question:

```
for chunk in chunks:
    print(''.join(str(x).rjust(5 if i else 2) for i, x in enumerate(chunk)))
```

**Update:** For every chunk it will first convert numbers to strings with `str` and then right justify them with [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) that uses space as default fill char. Since the first number on the row has width of `2` and rest of them have width of `5` [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is used to track the index so that correct argument can be passed to `rjust`. Enumerate returns tuples in form `(index, item)` and the index is then used in `5 if i else 2` to determine if number is first or not so width of `2` or `5` can be used respectively. Finally all the substrings are joined together for a row which is printed to screen.

Comment: this works perfectly, except that I have no idea why

Comment: Well, [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html)(chunk) creates a new list containing an index and the element for every element in the enumerated list...
for i,x in loops through the enumerated list
str(x) creates a string from a integer
rjust adds spaces so that the string is (5 or 2) large, where (5 or 2) depends on the index in the enumeration (element 0 adds 5, all the other add 2).
dont know if its clearer, but understand the steps, add this up, and you get how it works in total...

Comment: @RicardoMartinez Added a short explanation.

Comment: @SebastiaanMannem: Almost correct but you got the param passed to `rjust` wrong, `5 if i else 2` results to 2 in case i==0 and 5 in all other cases.

Comment: @ricardoMartinez: Would it help you if one was to change the one-liner into a block of code (maybe even with addition of some lines of comment)?